# What to do with tags that have multiple meanings?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

I was going to put a tag on this [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/175/who-besieged-karl-iv-at-siena) of karl-iv. On wikipedia, it says that his name in english is Charles IV. A simple [google search](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=charles%20iv&pbx=1&oq=charles%20iv&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3290l6245l1l6404l10l9l0l0l0l0l612l3021l2-3.2.1.2l9l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=555cba8207d23d1c&ion=1&biw=1440&bih=779) shows that there is also a Charles IV in Spain and France. Should we use charles-iv-france, charles-iv-spain, and charles-iv-hre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that we should specify the nation where it is necessary to avoid ambiguity. Rulers are the primary example, but it would also apply to anything else that may be ambiguous such as periods (eg. both China and Korea have three kingdoms eras) and cities (eg. Thebes in Egypt and Greece).

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be more appropriate to use two separate tags in an example like this. That way if someone is looking for questions pertaining to the person, they can searrch by name, while people looking for questions pertaining to the country will also find it. I think this would allow for a broader reach when trying to find information.

The whole point is to simplify the tags as much as possible. Of course, the problem is that not everyone will intuitively recognize the need to use both the name tag and the country tag, so there is the risk that only one or the other gets used. Even so, with an active core of users monitoring each question, it wouldn't be that big a deal to get the extra tag added if necessary.